# Java Google Translate API v2 "Daily Limit Exceeded"

Tags: java, api, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I've been calling the `API` just fine for many times during testing but today when I let plenty of clients use it, it started returning the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded",
      "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
}
```

My code is the following:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.translate.Translate;
import com.google.api.services.translate.model.TranslationsListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.translate.model.TranslationsResource;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GoogleTranslateAPI
{
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "MY-APPLICATION-NAME";
    private static final String API_KEY = "MY-API-KEY";

    private static final String DEFAULT_SOURCE_LANGUAGE = "en";

    public static String translate(String input, String targetLanguage) throws Exception
    {
        return translate(input, null, targetLanguage);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    public static String translate(String input, String sourceLanguage, String targetLanguage) throws Exception
    {
        // Watermark the Google translations
        if (!targetLanguage.equals(DEFAULT_SOURCE_LANGUAGE))
        {
            input += "<br>Translated with Google Translate. Please read the English version for most accuracy.";
        }

        Translate.Translations.List translationsList = buildTranslationsList(input, targetLanguage, sourceLanguage);
        TranslationsListResponse response = translationsList.execute();
        List<TranslationsResource> translations = response.getTranslations();
        int translationsCount = translations.size();

        if (translationsCount != 1)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected translations count: " + translationsCount);
        }

        TranslationsResource translationsResource = translations.get(0);
        return translationsResource.getTranslatedText();
    }

    private static Translate.Translations.List buildTranslationsList(String input, String targetLanguage, String sourceLanguage) throws Exception
    {
        Translate translate = buildTranslate();
        Translate.Translations.List translationsList = translate.new Translations()
                .list(Collections.singletonList(input), targetLanguage)
                .setSource(sourceLanguage);

        translationsList.setKey(API_KEY);
        return translationsList;
    }

    private static Translate buildTranslate() throws Exception
    {
        return new Translate.Builder(
                GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I checked my [`Google Console`](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis) and it says:

```
There is no traffic for this time period.
```

I changed the time period and clearly used the `API` but there is no data. Also, I enabled billing and entered valid billing information before starting to use the `API`. The translate `API` says that it's enabled. Of course I generated an `API key` for the project and replaced both placeholders (`API key` and `project name`) in the source code.

It seems like I'm doing everything right but `Google` won't let me use keep using it even though they may bill me for the usage so it won't return an error at least if I run out of quota. I can't even see how much quota I used or have left due to no data showing in my account.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you "_let plenty of clients use it_", you may have reached a limit. See this page for more info: https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas

Comment: It is unclear which specific quota you're hitting, so you better open an issue at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers to have someone to look into your specific project internally to have more details.